# Kotlin: How to call JobIntentService from Fragment?

Tags: kotlin, fragment, jobintentservice

I'm creating GPS tracking app. So I need to run this app at background (or foreground?). How can I call JobIntentService (SecondClass) class when I tap to button "Start" in Fragment (FirstClass)?

I looked for example at [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405841/geofence-triggering-issues-in-android/53411404#53411404) - but still I don't understand how to call JobIntentService class from Fragment class.

I try to call SecondClass like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968334/how-to-call-any-activity-from-fragment-android-studio-kotlin)):

`val contentIntent = Intent(context, SecondClass::class.java)`

But it ends with this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com...SecondClass: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com...SecondClass> cannot be instantiated`

Answer (score 0):

```
context?.run {
    JobIntentService.enqueueWork(
        applicationContext,
        SecondClass::class.java,
        100,// your id
        Intent(applicationContext, SecondClass::class.java)
    )
}
```

Don't forget to declare service in manifest in such way

```
<service
    android:name=".SecondClass"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks good but there's an error: `Unresolved reference: enqueueWork`. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207056/15309916 - but `SecondClass.enqueueWork` not works too.

Comment: @djlj yes, it is. Try via `JobIntentService.enqueueWork`

Comment: Yes! Gradle Build works right now but application crashes when i tap to "Start" with this error: `Scheduled service ComponentInfo{com...SecondClass} does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission`. I use `BIND_JOB_SERVICE` for a long time in the manifest. I tried delete it - without success.

Comment: @djlj see my answer at the end

Comment: I was using `android:permission="ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION|ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION|ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION|ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS|ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION|CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES|INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER|LOCATION_HARDWARE|android.permission.BLUETOOTH"`

I changed it to `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"`.

New error: `Unable to instantiate service com...SecondClass: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com...SecondClass> cannot be instantiated` :'(

Comment: I guess you added permission to incorrect place, it should be in `manifest/app/service`

Comment: I checked it 100×. It's in manifest/app/service. But still this error. Kotlin is amazing but I'm confused from this weird errors.

Comment: I solved it. I don't know how but it's solved. Thank you especially for `enqueueWork`.